# Override Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, preference, di.xml

How to override below file in module ?

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender.php
```

Comment: You can use preference in di.xml or intercept the method using plugin.

Comment: Did you get your answer? Or you need any help?

Comment: I have added answer. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Have you checked answer?

Comment: @devhs Are you able to do it?

Comment: Hello, let me check.

Answer (score 2):

With below code you can override CreditmemoSender.php file

> Step 1: Create di.xml file PackageName/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender" type="PackageName\Module\Model\Rewrite\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender" />
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create file CreditmemoSender.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Model/Rewrite/Order/Email/Sender

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Model\Rewrite\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\CreditmemoIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo as CreditmemoResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class CreditmemoSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender
{
    public function send(Creditmemo $creditmemo, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $creditmemo->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
            $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

            $transport = [
                'order' => $order,
                'order_id' => $order->getId(),
                'creditmemo' => $creditmemo,
                'creditmemo_id' => $creditmemo->getId(),
                'comment' => $creditmemo->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $creditmemo->getCustomerNote() : '',
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
                'store' => $order->getStore(),
                'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
                'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
                'order_data' => [
                    'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                    'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                    'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                    'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
                ]
            ];
            $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

            /**
             * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
             */
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before',
                ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
            );

            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $creditmemo->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $creditmemo->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Please write die("testing); in the beginning of send() function to check this overridden file is working or not for you.

Comment: Can you please approve and upvote this?

Comment: @zealouseWeb thanks this helped me